# Momentum scroll bug iOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, scroll, webkit-overflow-scrolling

I am trying to have momentum scrolling in my app on an element generated with vue's v-for. It works most of the time, but sometimes when I click somewhere else on the screen, or press a button the scroll becomes disabled.
This bug only happens when I have "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" but I need it for momentum scrolling.

Do you have any idea why the scroll becomes disabled ?
Here is the part of the code that is concerned by the problem.

Edit: The problem only occures on iOS devices (obviously with "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch")

Here is a small demo: https://github.com/dwerynith/Scroller

To reproduce the bug, all I have to do is access the app on an iPad/iPhone/iOS device and play with the scrolls and buttons. The scroll will eventually become disabled and come back after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some losing focus issue. Hard to tell without the working demo. The only thing I can think of is that- from what I recall- momentum scroll doesn't work with anything else than `overflow-y: scroll;`, so maybe this is causing the issue: `.channels-container {overflow-y: auto;}`

Comment: I added a repo where you can download a demo to reproduce the bug.